# How to align subnavigation and make it go right

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[image: Pic of Subnavigation and what I want to do with it]

My subnavigation for http://wegotbeats.com/ seems to not line up with the parent. Also, when it pops out it goes out to the left instead of to the right. How can I fix this so that the subnav lines up with parent and to make it go right instead of left? I am currently using OptimizePress theme via Wordpress. I included the HTML, if you need anything at all just let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body .container .navigation.fly-to-left ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;  //change
    right: auto; //change
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Not aligned but its got the sub navigation going in the right direction. The funny thing is I tried that exact same code on the wrong part of the css lol thanks again